# Are there any Geospatial OData Feeds?

Tags: web-service, ogc

I see that [OData](http://www.odata.org/) V3 has support for [geospatial types](http://www.odata.org/blog/2011/10/14/geospatial-properties).

Has anyone published a feed that uses the new geospatial data types?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A bit on the side, as I haven't used The OData standard, but I found: http://www.sensorpedia.com/ which is in closed beta, but according to [this presentation](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/system/files/Sensorpedia_Resseguie.pdf) (pdf) they use the OData standard